# Realm do not allow store nil in NSDate properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I create model like this:

```
@interface Course : RLMObject

@property NSString *courseId;
@property NSString *name;
@property NSDate *startDate;
@property NSDate *endDate;

@end
```

And I have courses without `endDate`. So app crashes when I try to save object with `NSNull` value in `NSDate` type. Property is not optional. How I can save optional `NSDate` in DB?

Comment: Hi! Can't you simply use a particular date to handle this case? For example, you could use 1970/01/01. Furthermore, If I well remember, realm does not allow to store in any case a Nil value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm does not currently support optional `NSDate` properties, but perhaps you can use `distantPast` / `distantFuture` to act as sentinel values?

Comment: Thank you. I see the same questions in 2013-2014 years, but I can't believe that  it is not implemented for today. In docs no info about it..